# find all groups of adjacent graph nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, clique-problem

I have a graph and it's nodes adjacent matrix.
The issue is to find all nodes adjacent "all to all". For example (at the picture) the result must be `[1,2,3,7]` all of this nodes connected together.
For any kind graph I need get get the list of all "all to all" nodes collection. How to solve it?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find a clique in a graph. Finding a subgraph that is clique in an NP complete problem. You can read through the material here http://www.dfki.de/~neumann/ie-seminar/presentations/finding_cliques.pdf They have mentioned multiple methods here.

Comment: Finding *a* clique is easy -- any edge is a clique.  Even finding a maxim*al* clique -- that is, a clique that cannot have any more vertices added to it while still remaining a clique -- can be done in poly-time.  Only finding a maxim*um* clique (which it seems is what the OP wants, though s/he isn't 100% clear) is NP-hard.